# Download PDF document with the help of selenium and Internet Explorer

Tags: python, selenium

I have read all the answers available in Stack Overflow regarding my problem. Try various possible methods but there is no answer available to my problem.

I am using selenium python for automating a task related to a tool for my organisation. **For downloading documents this tool only works in** `Internet Explorer browser`. I want to download a document from this tool and save it in a particular folder. Following are the steps that I have to perform

1. After performing some steps I have to click on view order form button. [image: click on view order form]
2. After clicking this button a second window opens(A pop up type). In this window a pdf document is open(probably with **adobe reader toolbar**) and I have to download this document with the help of my script and saves it in particular folder. **This document is only works in Ie browser.** I have switched to this window with my code [image: this is screenshot]

I have tried following code to do this task. Second Window opens with my code but I am not able to download my document

```
view_order_form = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@class='butCreateReport']")))
view_order_form.click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) #switching to second window where this pdf is opened
a = driver.page_source
print(a)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("S").perform() #I have tried shortcut Shift + Control + S which is shortcut in this second window pdf open by adobe reader toolbar
time.sleep(4)
actions.key_up(Keys.SHIFT).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

How to download this pdf document that opens in second window with the help of some link clicking on first window?

EDIT: I have disable "Adobe Reader Toolbar" in addons settings in Internet Explrore today. Now it is opening a dialogue in second window. I know how to handle this in Firefox & Chrome. But how to save this file in particular with folder with a specified name [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to the newly opened window. Here is how:

```
main_window = driver.current_window_handle
all_windows = driver.window_handles
for w in all_windows:
    if w != main_window:
        pdf_window = w
            driver.switch_to.window(pdf_window)
```

Now your driver is operating on the pdf_window. You find your elements and use ActionChains to download the doc.

Even better, you can make your browser not to open the pdf file, but download instead of that. Here's [how to do](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-disable-chromes-pdf-viewer/) it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. As you can see I have  switched.  to second window already in my code and also this tool is only working in Internet Explorer only and not in Chrome browser. So it do not work in my case and I need to find other answer

Comment: You did change to second window. Sorry, I missed that part. Why not make no pdf viewer plugin available in the browser, then it should have no choice but to download the pdf.

Comment: how to do that? Do you have any idea to do it in selenium code and Internet  Explorer driver settings plugin. If yes please answer